# Connecting to database and Inserting data

Tags: android

MainActivty.java

```
package com.data.database;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b;
EditText e1;
String response="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.namee);

}
public void SUBMIT(View view){
String name=e1.getText().toString();
String method="register";
BackgroudTask backgroudTask=new BackgroudTask(this);
backgroudTask.execute(method,name);

}

}
```

BackgroudTask.java

```
package com.data.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroudTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context ctx;
BackgroudTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx=ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String link="http://comeon.byethost14.com/name.php";
    String method=params[0];
    if(method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=     (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new  OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("NAME","UTF- 8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();
            InputStream is=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    is.close();
            return  "Registration Success";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}


protected void onProgressUpdate(Void values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.data.database">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

content_main.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.data.database.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/name_text"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/namee"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="53dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit_button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/namee"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:onClick="SUBMIT"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is My code.I dont see any change in my database when i run the application in my phone and try to enter a name and submit it.I am trying to do it for the first time.The php scripts are ok as i checked them by their URLs in the URL of browsers and recieving correct Outputs and messages.I even tried to run the php script which is supposed to look after the insertion of data in the database and it worked flawlessly.Any kind help will be nice.Thank You.Another Thing Which I thought will be helpful,The Message "Resgistraion Success" is shown everytime i click on the Button Submit.

Comment: That is an onClick for the Button.

Comment: Do your server receive the request when you run your app?

Comment: I dont no how do i find out that???

Comment: And how will it help me?

Comment: Is `"Registration Success"` shown?

Comment: So you mean you don't see changes in the database in the server side?

Comment: Yes I dont see records getting added to the tables which i want.

Comment: Can't you debug your server code to see whether it receives the request and whether the data sent is correct?

Comment: Instead of using URLEncoder.encode(), try to use `String data = "NAME="+name;`. Or just log your `data` string and check whether it is actually what you want.